# iPhone, method returns an objective-c object with a +1 retain count

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I kind of understand why I'm getting this analyzer warning. Because I'm using an object that is being passed in. I've tried `autorelease` and `retain` however these cause me other problems like `unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

The aim of my CommonUI function is to re-use code, but I have to cater for `addSubView` and `presentModalViewController`.

Perhaps I'm doing some obvious wrong ?

[image]

Comment: need to see your HelpViewController's initWithNibName:bundle:onPage: method code please

Comment: Hope you don't mind but I've improved your code indentation a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here.

First, if you call `[vc release]` (as the other answers suggest), you'll certainly make the analyzer happy but likely crash the app. A view controller's view doesn't retain the controller, so any button targets in the view will be pointing to garbage.

You will need to somehow keep the `HelpViewController` retained for as long as it is showing up onscreen. The "parent" view controller should likely retain it somehow. You could autorelease it, and return it. Then whomever calls `showHelpClick...` would retain the returned controller.

Second, you don't need to have the `(UIViewController *)vc` passed in as an argument.

Comment: Yes your right, I have a button which crashes the app. Do you have a suggestion, I'd be happy to change my CommonUI function, but I don`t really want to change the Getting started code.

Comment: GettingStartedViewController will need to retain the HelpViewController; it's as simple as that and is a common paradigm (just like parent views retain their child views).

Comment: Right, so what do i do to fix my CommonUI function to stop the analyzer warning?

Comment: Like my answer above, have it return the autoreleased HelpViewController, and the GettingStarted code that calls it should retain the returned value. i.e. after `[vw addSubview...]`, `return [vc autorelease];` and in GettingStarted, `self.helpController = [cui showHelp...]`, where `helpController` is a retained property. Remember to release it in GettingStarted's dealloc.

Comment: Thanks for straightening me out Jason. I wasn't certain that it it would retain it. I'm downvoting myself, though perhaps deleting it is the better option -- not sure what the appropriate etiquette is here.

Comment: Jules, change the return type to `UIViewController *`, and the rest of my answers should be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code like this:

```
HelpViewController *helpvc = [[HelpViewController alloc] init....];
[vw addSubview:helpvc.view];
[helpcv release];
```

I think you don't need to pass the other VC.

Comment: This will crash the app if any events from subviews of the HelpViewController view have the HelpViewController as their target.